# RabbitMq single Consumer with multiple queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to create single consumer(Generic Listener) for multiple queues.The consumer should listen multiple queues.

Lets see in the example

```
        channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: "fanout");

        var queueName = "QeueueName.Instance1";
        channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                          exchange: "logs",
                          routingKey: "");

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for logs.");

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] {0}", message);
        };
```

I want to associate the consumer with dynamic no of queues and they will 
 increase time to time so how i will associate consumer to future created queues.I have created a window service for the same so do i have to loop all the queues and associate with consumer and for the future created queues I should add them in the consumer queue list.

Comment: Yes, and? What's the problem you're having? RabbitMQ is not a programming language, so you're going to need to show us the code you need help with.

Comment: Man i have updated my question plz help if u have any idea abt this, its urgent, I m stuck into this.

Answer (score 6):

When I first read your question I didn't think you could bind one consumer to multiple queues, but I just tried this and it works fine:

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            VirtualHost = "testHost1",
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
            Port = 5672,
        };

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        var channel = connection.CreateModel();
        channel.ExchangeDeclare("testExchange1", ExchangeType.Fanout);
        channel.QueueDeclare("testQueue1");
        channel.QueueDeclare("testQueue2");
        channel.QueueBind("testQueue1", "testExchange1", "");
        channel.QueueBind("testQueue2", "testExchange1", "");

        var consumer1 = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer1.Received += Consumer1OnReceived;

        channel.BasicConsume("testQueue1", false, consumer1);
        channel.BasicConsume("testQueue2", false, consumer1);
```

Note that your code doesn't include a call to `BasicConsume()`. Your consumer won't receive anything without it.